# Fix files "corrupted" by Perl

Tags: perl

I have a bunch of files that were created using this code:

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $xl = get("http://www.somewhere.com/file.xls");
open(my $outf, '>', "C:/file.xls") || die $!;
print $outf $xl;
```

Only recently did I realize that I should have been using `'>:raw'` in the filehandle rather than just `'>'`. So now I have a bunch of files that have been modified in some way that prevents Excel from opening them.

My question is whether there is some processing I can do with Perl to these files to get back to the original Excel files. In other words, is it possible to figure out what edits would have been made to the file that I can undo with a new Perl script?

Comment: I doubt it. Some of the changes remove information.

Comment: `>` mode converts `'\n'` to `'\n\r'` on Windows (an may be some other stuff). You could try to do the reverse conversion. However, that's not guaranteed to succeed: what if you had a legitimate `'\n\r'` there?

Comment: @Arkadiy, It converts `\n` to `\r\n`. It also disables any default encoding, but chances are there were none.

Comment: @Arkadiy if there was a legitimate `\r\n` it would become `\r\r\n`, and the inverse transformation will do exactly the right thing.

Comment: @hobbs: ouch. Right you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It converted LF to CRLF. You can simply change any instance of CRLF back to LF.

```
my $qfn_in  = $qfn;
my $qfn_out = $qfn . ".new";

open(my $fh_in,  '<:raw', $qfn_in ) or die $!;
open(my $fh_out, '>:raw', $qfn_out) or die $!;

while (<$fh_in>) {
   s/\r\n\z/\n/;
   print($fh_out $_);
}
```

Or

```
my $qfn_in  = $qfn;
my $qfn_out = $qfn . ".new";

open(my $fh_in,  '<:raw:crlf', $qfn_in ) or die $!;
open(my $fh_out, '>:raw',      $qfn_out) or die $!;

print($fh_out $_) while <$fh_in>;
```

If you have `dos2unix`, you could also use that. (Though JRFerguson says that his version of it will corrupt files with character `1A` in it.)

Comment: `dos2uxix` and 'unix2os' also handle the ^Z found at the end of MSDOS-based files in addition to the CRLF/LF translations.

Comment: What is meant by `\z`?

Comment: @JoopEggen `\z` is the end of string, unlike `$` (which is EOS or newline at EOS, or end of line if `/m` was used).

Comment: Independent of platform, a `:raw:crlf` layer should work quite nice.

Comment: @Joop Eggen, It's similar to `$`. `/$/` means `/\n?\z/`. I always anchor my patterns as much as possible because it can help reduce backtracking. Here, it doesn't make any difference; it was included out of habit.

Comment: Actually, Perl normalized `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` into `\n`. Converting every ocurrence of `\n` into `\r\n` won't necessarily revert the file to it's original state.

Comment: @Havenard, No, it didn't. It converted LF to CRLF like I said. Test before contradicting someone. `perl -e"print qq{\r\0\n\0\r\n}" | perl -E"binmode STDIN; local $/; say unpack 'H*', $_ for split /\0/, <STDIN>;"`

Comment: @JRFerguson, Mine doesn't. Added warning to my answer.

Comment: @ikegami and what it does when the file has just an `\n` then? You cannot guarantee that a random binary file has absolutely no occurrence of `\r` or `\n` but only `\r\n` together. It's not about Perl, it's about messing with any binary file.

Comment: @Havenard, Who said anything about random binary file? The question is about fixing the files broken by the OP's code. Those files cannot have "just an `\n`".

Comment: Lets put it another way. OP's code normalized occurrences of CR, LF and CRLF into CRLF. There is no more CR and LF in OP's output file, there are only CRLFs now. Your code "fixes" that by converted all those CRLFs into LFs. Howover, bytes that were originally CR and CRLF will now all be LF. Files that originally didn't have CR and CRLF will be fixed, but if they had, they will remain broken.